# How to use an object from another userform in vbscript?

Tags: vba, userform, catia

I am working with multiple userforms in vbscript.

I am creating an object in a userform and trying to call it in another userform.
I tried declaring the object as Public in both the userforms but still I am not able to acess the object from another userform.

Look Forward for your help.

Thanks in advance.

Userform1:

```
        Public Inner_V1 As Object
        Private Sub Inner_V1_CD_Click()

 'Auswahlfenster ausblenden
  Input_selection2.Hide

'Dim myDoc As Document
Set myDoc = CATIA.ActiveDocument

On Error Resume Next

Set ActivePart = CATIA.ActiveDocument.Part

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        On Error GoTo 0
        Box = MsgBox("Das geöffnete Dokument ist kein CATPart!" + Chr(10) + "Das Makro wird beendet", vbExclamation, "Falscher Dateityp")
        Unload Input_selection2
        Exit Sub
    End If

' Selektion definieren und leeren ----
Dim UserSel As Object
Set UserSel = myDoc.Selection
UserSel.Clear
'-------------------------------------

' User wählt die Fläche aus #############################################################################

    ' Auswahl festlegen -------------------
    Dim Was1(0)
    Was1(0) = "HybridShape"
    '--------------------------------------

    Dim Auswahl                                         'Wird für die SelectElement2 Methode benötigt (Auswahl durch User)
    Auswahl = UserSel.SelectElement2(Was1, "Bitte die Fläche auswählen.", False)

    If Auswahl = "Normal" Then
        Set Inner_V1 = UserSel.Item(1).Value
        Inner_V1.Value = Inner_V1.Name
    Else
        Unload Input_selection2
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Selektion freigeben -----------------------------------------------------
    UserSel.Clear                           'User-Auswahl löschen

  'Auswahlfenster anzeigen
   Input_selection2.Show

   End Sub
```

Userform2:

```
           Private Sub Weiter_Click()

           Set hybridBodies1 = part1.HybridBodies

           Set hybridBody1 = hybridBodies1.Add()
           hybridBody1.Name = "test"

           Set reference1 = part1.CreateReferenceFromObject(Inner_V1)
           Set reference2 = part1.CreateReferenceFromObject(Guide_curve)

           Set sweep_v1 = hybridShapeFactory1.AddNewSweepExplicit(reference1, reference2)
           Set reference3 = part1.CreateReferenceFromObject(Support_V)

           hybridBody1.AppendHybridShape sweep_v1

           End Sub
```

Here, Inner_V1 is the object which i Need to use from Userform1.

Comment: Do you mean VBA? In what application?

Comment: Yes VBA Im using to develop macro in CATIA

Comment: Not sure about CATIA but in Excel VBA (and in VBA in general) there aren't static objects in classes and forms. You need to place global variables in a separate module.

Comment: I did declare the object variable as public in the main module as well. But still im not able to acess the object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple I just have to call Userform1.Inner_V1

Answer (score 0):

Add a Property to the form containing the object.

E.g.

**UserForm1**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Click()
    Dim uf2 As UserForm2
    Set uf2 = New UserForm2

    uf2.Col.Add Now, "K"

    uf2.Show
End Sub
```

**UserForm2**

```
Private mCol As Collection

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set mCol = New Collection
End Sub

Public Property Get Col() As Collection
    Set Col = mCol
End Property

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    MsgBox mCol("K")
End Sub
```

Comment: UserForm2  is just a UserForm, If its a VBA environment hosting Microsoft Forms (as it presumably is) then its fine.

Comment: Alex Thank you for your reply. But i could not understand your code. In the Userform1:                                                                                                                     I am declaring an object as "Public object1 As Object"  and settin a value. Which I am not able to get it                                                                                      Userform2:                                                                                                                 Here I am trying to get the value of the object1.

Comment: My *example* uses a `Collection`, substitute that with your object.

Comment: When i give.... "Set Inner_V11 = New Object"  I get a error message "Expected: Identifier"

Comment: You will need to edit your question and add the relevant code